# How to cache function result in scala

Tags: scala

Say I implement a case class that computes some measures for the [confusion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix)

```
case class Measure(tp: Int, fp: Int, fn: Int){
  require(tp < 0); require(fp < 0); require(fn < 0)

  def precision: Double = tp / (tp + fp)
  def recall: Double = tp / (tp + fn)
  def fMeasure: Double = 2 * (precision * recall) / (precision + recall)
}
```

I had some question in regards to how Scala would handle these functions:

1. If someone call `fMeasure`, would `precision` and `recall` both be called twice? Or would Scala compiler figure out that we are using the same value and cache the result for the first call and re-use memorized value for the second calling
2. If someone called `precision` and `recall` function before previously, would those results be cached somewhere so that `fMeasure` would not have to recompute `precision` and `recall`?

If both do not end with any sort of computation optimization, then is there a specifically "scala" way of caching the result? Coming from Java background, I would have created a field called `precision` and `recall` and check for the `null` to cache the result.

Comment: Just lookup function memoization in Scala.

Comment: I don't see the point in having `def` values or for caching (memoize) any of the results. Every instance of `Measure` will have it's own constructor values. Use `val` instead of `def` and everything is calculated once and only once.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First there is a bug in the code.

Rewrite function precision to

```
def precision: Double = tp.toDouble / (tp.toDouble + fp.toDouble)
```

and similarly you have to fix the recall function.

Q. If someone call fMeasure, would precision and recall both be called twice?

Ans. Yes. They would be called twice.

Paraphrasing the second question.

Q. Is there any way to prevent it being called twice.

Ans. Yes. Use lazy vals.

So the code can be something like. I have eliminated the defs and used lazy vals instead because it wasnt apparent why you need defs here.

```
case class Measure(tp: Int, fp: Int, fn: Int){
  require(tp < 0); require(fp < 0); require(fn < 0)

  lazy val precision = tp.toDouble / (tp.toDouble + fp.toDouble)
  lazy val recall = tp.toDouble / (tp.toDouble + fn.toDouble)
  lazy val fMeasure = 2 * (precisionVal * recallVal) / (precisionVal + recallVal)

}
```

There is a cost associated with lazy vals. See this - https://dzone.com/articles/cost-laziness

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! However, the article seems to suggest that using a `lazy val` is not much problem? ("The numbers show that lazy vals performance penalty is quite small and can be ignored in practice.")

Comment: You are correct. Usually people reading the article would have the question on performance / the impact of using a lazy val. Hence I added the reference.